# Decoder model selection for sequence-to-sequence ASR with XLS-R

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface, speech-to-text

I am new to building models for Speech ASR. I want to build a model for Speech Transcription in Urdu. I used XLS-R (following the example by Patric von Platen on Huggingface Colab notebook. [My notebook can be found](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wpvCwAKNpX4wgDuHh2Bm3stUAVp-i3hY?usp=sharing)) as it is pre-trained on Urdu too. I trained the model on Common Voice Urdu dataset, but the Word Error Rate (WER) is 50%, which is bad. I want to improve it by using a better decoder model, as suggested in the original tutorial notebook.

My question is:

- For my problem, which decoder models can I use? XLS-R is a good speech encoder model as it is pre-trained in 128 languages including Urdu, which model or models should work well with it?
- Should I build a decoder model from scratch, or should I use a pre-trained decoder model and fine-tune it? What role does CTC compatibility play in it?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, or any link to a notebook of someone working on similar problem. Thank you.